# What's the deal with prefixes? Is Mi smallest amount that could be transferred?

Tags: transaction, token

I just received 1 Mi as test. And it seems to be smallest amount to transfer. So I guess that's the reason that IOTA is dubbed MIOTA.

But when I check https://thetangle.org/statistics/tokens-distribution there are wallets with less than 1Mi amount in them. How is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are referring to as 1 Mi is 1 MIOTA, which stands for 1 million IOTA.

1 MIOTA is the standard **traded** amount of IOTA on exchanges, but the you can divide it into 1 million single IOTAs which is the smallest amount to transfer. By holding 1 MIOTA you have the capability of sending 1 million 1 IOTA transactions.

See the following image for the full breakdown:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should explain it. A single iota is the smallest of value, a Mi megaIOTA is 1,000,000 iota:

[image]